# pandas dataframe. create or add column, best method

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Does anyone have a nice way so that, in a loop, you will either create a new dataframe, or if it does exists, just add a column to it ?

I do that for the moment, but i'm pretty sure there is a more elegant way to do it:

```
for fund in df:
    _signal = computeSignal(someVar)
    if 'dfSignal' not in locals():
        dfSignal = pd.DataFrame(_signal, index = df.index, columns = [fund])
    else:
        dfSignal[fund]=pd.DataFrame(_signal,index = df.index)
```

anyone ?

Regards,
Julien

Answer (score 2):

I'd wrap this in a `try`/`except` construct:

```
dct = {k: _signal for k in df}
try:
    dfSignal = dfSignal.assign(**dct)
except:
    dfSignal = pd.DataFrame(dct, df.index)
```